# Not irreducible = reducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Sorry this is more of a language issue. If $f(x) \in F[x]$, and if $f$ is not irreducible, does it mean it is reducible? Since this is just a language question, I am allowing $F$ to be a commutative ring with unity instead of a field like usual.

Comment: @angryavian, thanks

Comment: Units in $F^{\times}$ are probably not called reducible

Comment: @angryavian Wikipedia forgot to consider zero and units (or constants).  Wikipedia is far from authoritative.